# Exclude categories and subcategories in QueryLoop

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

I want a QueryLoop that exclude some categories and its subcategories,

I have this:

```
        $args = array(
            'category__not_in' => array( 2, 6 ),
        );
```

this exclude the categories, 2 and 6 , but no its subcategories, what can I do?

====== Update =======
This is what I did, but now I'm searching for a better solution:

```
        $excludes = array(2,6);
        $ex_childs = array();

        foreach($excludes as $exclude){
             $a = get_categories('child_of='.$exclude);
            foreach($a as $key => $value){
                $ex_childs[] =  $value->cat_ID;
            }
        }           

        $all_excludes = array_merge($excludes, $ex_childs);

        $args = array(
            'category__not_in' => $all_excludes
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like [this](http://wpengineer.com/876/exclude-subcategories-in-a-loop/) where you filter the posts once the WP_Query gets them?

Comment: Thanks, I already did something similar, but now I'm searching for a better solution,